# Showing there exists a positive solution to $x^4+x^3=a.$

Tags: analysis

I have been given the question show there exists a solution $x \in [0,\infty)$ to $x^3+x^4=2020$.

I would normally try factorise the question and show the exact solutions however I feel there should be a better way to do it, does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: "Show that there exists" is a hint.  You are not necessarily expected to find the solution, just to prove that there is one.  You should have some theorems that say there is a solution in a given range based on some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

By the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), $$f(x)=x^3+x^4-2020=0$$ 
has a positive root between $6$ and $7$. By the rational root test, it has no rational root.

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

More accessibly, you want to find an interval on which the graph of $f(x) = x^3 + x^4 - 2020$ crosses the $x$ axis, or the function $f(x)$ changes sign.

Since $f(x)$ is continuous, a change of sign implies $x^3 + x^4 - 2020$ is zero at at least one point in the interval.

In this case, consider the interval $[6, 7]$.

$f(6) = -508 <0$

$f(7) = 724 > 0$

Hence since $f(x)$ has changed sign on $[6, 7]$ (and it is continuous), there exists a value of $x \in [6, 7]$ for which $f(x) = 0$. In other words, there is a solution to the equation $x^3 + x^4 = 2020$.

You can use [Interval Bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to get a smaller interval containing the root.

Alternatively, you could use calculus to compute the turning points and their nature and use this to justify that there is a positive root.